# Schemy question..

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Here is where I got lost .. I have a scheme Y over k (an algebraically 
closed field), in it I have an irreducible closed subscheme X of 
finite type (do I need finite type?).  I also know that X is 
universally closed (over k) and separated (do I need separated?) .. 
then why is it that X should be either a point or Y itself?

Comment: To the downvoter: that's not really a nice welcome for quantum, so I upvoted the question again.

Comment: (Although I agree that this is not an ideal Mathoverflow question.)

Comment: Welcome to MO! It looks like your question comes from other sources than pure curiosity. Perhaps reproducing the exact question here would help us answer it better.    

Comment: hmm... I have the impression that you didn't read http://mathoverflow.net/howtoask in detail. Maybe you can get very helpful answers if you rephrase your question a little bit.

Comment: Are you mixing up the term "irreducible scheme" with the term "irreducible representation", where the meaning is very different?

Answer (score 5):

I don't get it. You are saying exactly that $X$ should be proper over $k$. Embed $X = \mathbb{P}^1(\mathbb{C})$ - which is proper over $\mathbb{C}$ - in $Y = \mathbb{P}^2(\mathbb{C})$ as a closed subscheme. That's a counterexample?

Comment: It also seems that taking $X$ disjoint union something else gives a counterexample, so I think we need more assumptions about these schemes.